# Gauss-Bonnet on a finite, non-compact surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $D$ be a two dimensional (simply connected) compact surface with boundary and a consider a point $p\in D$. Since $D \backslash\{p\}$ is no longer compact, the Gauss-Bonnet identity does not immediately apply, then is there any Gauss-Bonnet-like global constraint on the curvature of $D \backslash \{p\}$ (or in general, about $D \backslash\{\text{measure zero set}\}$) ?

Comment: Are you asking (in effect) whether there are _a priori_ bounds for "the amount of curvature that can be concentrated at one point of a disk or sphere"? <> If so, offhand it looks as if "less than $2\pi$, but there is no lower bound". (One can achieve these values with cone vertices.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Basically I'm looking for a Gauss-Bonnet theorem for compact surfaces with finitely many points removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surface with a cone point may be viewed as having infinite curvature at the vertex, in such a way that the *integral of the curvature at the vertex* is equal to $2\pi$ minus the incident angle. The Gauss-Bonnet theorem holds for such surfaces.

If $C > 0$ is arbitrary, there exists a smooth, flat metric on the punctured unit disk for which the total geodesic curvature of the boundary is $C$. (In fact, these can be embedded isometrically in flat Euclidean $3$-space as cones with arbitrary positive angle at the vertex, except the vertex is removed.)

Because we can concentrate curvature at a vertex (maintaining the Gauss-Bonnet theorem) then remove the vertex (subtracting $2\pi - C$ from one side), there is no Gauss-Bonnet theorem for punctured surfaces.