# Gauß-Bonnet for non-compact manifolds

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, curvature

Is there a reasonable approach

- to extend the Gauß-Bonnet theorem to non-compact manifolds?
- and use this to distinguish between i) the 2-sphere and ii) the punctured 2-sphere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gauss-Bonnet on a finite, non-compact surface.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182030/gauss-bonnet-on-a-finite-non-compact-surface)

Comment: The answer is talking about the compact, flat unit disc, whereas I am asking for the curved 2-sphere. I don’t see how to translate the given answer to my case.

Comment: The linked answer explains why Gauss-Bonnet does not extend to punctured surfaces, which addresses the first bullet point. <> For the second, a sphere is compact and a punctured sphere is not, which presumably distinguishes them...?

Comment: The distinction between a sphere and a punctured sphere due to compactness vs. non-compactness is clear and was never the question. The question was if some extension of the Gauß-Bonnet theorem to the non-compact case can be used to distinguish them. From what I understand this is not the case b/c there is no such theorem in the non-compact case.

Comment: Yes, there is no extension; an arbitrary amount of "total Gaussian curvature" $k < 2\pi$ can be accumulated at one point, and deleted by puncturing at that point.